# Can't override the selected row background color

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I've been trying to do this for too long already. It can't be a specificity issue since I went overboard and added new unique classes and an id to the row element while tracing it back to `body` element - yet the background color still would not change. The color of the text, the height of the row etc. all change totally.

I attempt to attack the `.selected` class which bootstrap-table automatically adds on to selected rows. I have also tried using my own new `.highlighted` class which is toggled via jQuery and the BT `onCheck` property.

I've exhausted the options I can think of. I don't understand why this specific property will not budge.

code snippets:

```
//Table setup. (data is retrieved through JSON response) Columns are built from JSON response. Everything works well and good.

$('#results-table').bootstrapTable({

            data: new_result,
            columns: columns,
            sortable: true,
            pagination: true,
            search: true,
            showColumns: true,
            sortName: "lastname",
            striped: false,
            clickToSelect: true,
            maintainSelected: true,
            onClickRow: function(e, row, element){highlightRow(e, row, element);},
        });


//initiated when onCheck event occurs. 

function highlightRow(e, row, element){
    $(row).toggleClass("highlighted");
    console.log("highlightRow Worked.");
}

// CSS (I have also tried a version with maximum specificity as mention above.

tr.highlighted {
background-color: var(--site-yellow) !important;
color: green;
```

Any idea what to do? I want to change that green into my palette yellow.

Comment: Your style is loaded? Check in inspect, please. It might be a caching issue

Comment: Yeah it's definitely loaded. Plus i play with the webdev console to try and change styles etc. but this 1 parameter will not yield to any changes. Peculiar. I'm thinking of just embracing the grey and that's it.

Comment: One thing I can't understand: What's with that var --site-yellow in your css?

Comment: @sTx To be honest I have no idea why i got fixed on this format for css color variables, but i started with it and now just go along with it for the sake of consistency. I think i expected more complex mechanism to follow and wanted to be as specific as possible. I learn as i go along :-)

Comment: the idea is that `background-color: var(--site-yellow) !important;` is not a valid CSS or SASS code

Comment: @sTx But it works for me on any other element i have applied it to except for the above mentioned problem.

Comment: now that I've searched it does [exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)